# json string is not converting into object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Here is the **server side code** I am trying to send json

```
$x = array();
$timestamp = strtotime('22-09-2008'); 
$x["x"] = $timestamp;
$x["y"] = 22;

$val = '[{ "name": "weight", "dataPoints": ['.json_encode($x).'] }]';
echo json_encode($val);
```

So output for above code looks like

```
   "[{ \"name\": \"weight\", \"dataPoints\": [{\"x\":1222041600,\"y\":22}] }]"
```

Below is the **client side code** I get the data via Jquery getJSON

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "https://domain/gettracker.php?id="+id, function(data) {

 console.log(data);

})
```

I suppose getJson converts json to object automatically , but it logs the raw json like below

```
"[ {  name: "weight", dataPoints: [{"x":1222041600,"y":22}] } ]"
```

I tried to do json parse , but i get error.

I guess I am not sending the data properly via php.Can some one guide me ?

Comment: Declare the var $x as an array initially perhaps?

Comment: Uhm. `$val` is a **string**.  `json_encode($val)` encodes that string as JSON, so you get `"....."` which is valid JSON. jQuery is calling `JSON.parse`, which returns the `....` part. It works perfectly fine, just not like you intended because you are not preparing your data correctly. I recommend to read the documentation and examples about `json_decode`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: edited question...please check again

Comment: `json_encode` converts the value to JSON (and returns a string). If you are already having a string containing JSON, you don't want to call `json_encode` on it. Makes sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON string is not valid - the property names should be enclosed in double quotes - `"`, and you don't need to encode the string again.

```
$val = '[{ "name": "weight", "dataPoints": ['.json_encode($x).'] }]';
echo $val;
```

Or better yet, use `json_encode` to create the string for you:

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'weight',
    'dataPoints' => $x
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Just to be clear (for future readers): It does not not work because the string value is incorrect (at least that's not the main issue). The issue is that the OP tries to JSON encode a *string*.

Comment: edited question , your first solution not working, 2nd solution is working fine ,,thank you

Comment: @Vishnu: I think you missed the part where `echo json_encode($val);` becomes `echo $val;`. But yeah, the second solution is the way to go.

Comment: oh yea , both solution working...but 2nd solution looks perfect :)